# Changing .text() depending on the window size with jQuery

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, resize

I've got a simple function that finds and shows the first sentence of every paragraph:

```
function firstSentence(){
  $('p').each(function(){
      var p = $(this).text();
      var s = p.split('.');
      var f = s[0];
      $(this).text(f + '...');
     });
}
```

And I use it when the window size is less than 600:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 600) {
    firstSentence();
     } else {
        // back to normal please!
    }
});
```

However, when the user resizes their window above 600, the content obviously does not change back.

What is the best way for the content to be reverted, if the user resizes to a larger window ( `> 600`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you do anything else, you need to store the original text in each paragraph. E.g. like this:

```
var originalTexts = $('p').map(function () {
    return $(this).text();
});
```

and then, for your "back to normal code":

```
$('p').each(function (key) {
    $(this).text(originalTexts[key]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I've never seen `.map()` before. So the first of `originalTexts[key]` is the first paragraph of `.each()`?

Comment: yep! $.map creates arrays: checkout the docs [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

Comment: I was going to post a lengthy answer on storing the original text in a hidden div on page load and hiding or showing each div based on the window size but then this answer blew my mind. KISS at its best

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain this is perfect but it will give you an idea

```
function origSentence(){
$('p').each(function(){
var o = $(this).text()}}
```

then

```
} else {
prigSentence()
```

Not forgetting this all over again on (doc).rdy.

Comment: Thanks, the 'back to normal code' is nothing as of yet. I'm not sure how to revert the firstSentence(), or capture the `.text()` in its original state.